# How to get batch script location which present specific folder using batch script(programmatically)

Tags: batch-file

I have update.bat file which can be present in any directory. Now I want to get the current location where this bat file is present. but the thing is I want this location in update.bat file itself. So how can I get the current location of this .bat file and use that location in the same bat file?

Comment: Can you clarify your terminology please? A "batch file" is most often a script run by a command interpreter in DOS or Windows. If it is to be interpreted by bash, it would be a "bash script" or more generically a "shell script". What operating system are you using? What do you see when you run `echo $BASH_VERSION` at a command prompt?

Comment: I am using OS as WINDOWS

Comment: `%~dp0` is the **d**rive and **p**ath of your script. (`%%~dpnx` or shorter `%%~f0` or `%~0` is the full name of your script.

Answer (score 2):

You should write like this :

```bat
@echo off
echo The working directory is : %~dp0
echo(
echo The Fullpath of this batch script is : %0
pause
```